# GraphDracula: How to detect onclick and onmouseover events?

Tags: javascript, raphael, graph-drawing

[GraphDracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/) is a nice simple small graph visualization library based on RaphaelJS. However two very important things I would want it to detect are onmouseover (over a node) and onclick (over a node again).

e.g. In their most basic example, a mouseover on "cherry" node should give some extra details about cherry. Clicking it shall pop an alert box.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by iterating through the nodes in the graph object and adding Raphael handlers on the `shape` object: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/65Mpy/

```
var g = new Graph();
//Rest of code
for(var i in g.nodelist){
   g.nodelist[i].shape.mouseover(console.log)
   g.nodelist[i].shape.click(console.log)
}
```

Comment: It seems that they changed "nodelist" to "nodes"